# Информационная безопасность - это интересно?

Tags: безопасность

Люди , учащиеся, работающие по специальности ИБ или просто знакомые с этой сферой, вы можете назвать её интересной и увлекательной? Что именно вас в ней интересует , а что бесит больше всего?

Comment: Этот вопрос оффтопик на этом сайте

Comment: Задайте этот вопрос на [мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Несмотря на то, что вопрос задан не в том месте, всё же отвечу. ИБ сама по себе очень интересна, но это утверждение в России сильно зависит от географии. Все проекты которые делаются по всей России придумываются и подготавливаются специалистами в Москве (как правило), а для регионов остается простая схема участия в ИБ: получить посылку из центрального управления, распаковать, вставить в стойку, подключить всё это по приложенной схеме, step-by-step выполнить приложенную инструкцию (которая разработана в Москве и просто, как правило содержит последовательности типа "тыкни мышкой сюда, нажми на клавиатуре то-то") и всё. То есть в регионах специалист по ИБ выполняет мероприятия квалификации Техник, а не Специалист.

НО! Всё описанное выше справедливо для гос.организаций, а в частном секторе как таковой ИБ нет, и должностей таких нет (я про Россию без Москвы). В частном секторе, ты системный администратор, выполняющий задачи специалиста по ИБ в меру возможностей, выполняющий обязанности ИТ-техника меняющий мышки и так далее. К сожалению...

Answer (score 0):

Хоть вопрос и оффтоп,  всё же отвечу: ИБ -  интересная тема. Существует множество ресурсов по Bug-hunting'у. Если хотите влиться в тему ИБ,  то  существует множество сайтов,  которые дают вам возможность легально принять участие в поиске багов,  и получить за это деньги/очки. Мог бы дать более развернутый ответ,  но так как вопрос ОТ,  то написал кратко.

Ресурсы для старта:

> [OWASP](https://owasp.org)

> [PortSwigger](https://portswigger.net)

> [H1](https://hackerone.com)

> [Bugcrowd](https://bugcrowd.com)

> [Intigriti](https://intigriti.com)

> [Red Team Blogs](https://redteams.net/)

> [Blue Team Blogs](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-e&q=Blue%20Team%20Blogs)

> White Hat Conf.

> Black Hat Conf.

и так далее...

Comment: А можно нелегально искать баги? :)

Comment: Можно и нелегально. Предположим,  вы сканируете сеть организации, которая не участвует в программе поиска багов,  и вам удалось залить шелл на сервер. Это преступление,  если вы не сообщите организации об этом. Если же сообщите,  то вас так же могут привлечь за незаконное тестирование.

Comment: Так нелегальность же не в поиске багов, а в нелегальном доступе к коду или нелегальной эксплуатации найденных багов

Comment: Нашёл -> Проэксплуатировал.

Comment: Признаться,  я юридические тонкости не знаю,  но вижу так,  что если я что-то ищу на сайте какого_то банка, то гости ко мне наведаются. Особенно,  если я сканирую  сеть, и так далее.

Comment: Спасибо всем большое за ответы) да... я новичок на стэке, буду внимателен в следующий раз